# Reordering columns after a merge

Tags: sas

In my SAS program, I am merging two data sets into one, and in the end I want to reorder the columns. My code is below. The merged data set has columns like `KEY FOO BAR NEWKEY`

```
DATA COMBINED;
    MERGE SET1(IN=IN1) SET2(IN=IN2);
    BY KEY;
    IF (IN1=1 AND IN2=1);
RUN;

DATA COMBINED;
    SET COMBINED;
    RETAIN NEWKEY;
RUN;
```

My intention is to move the `NEWKEY` column to become the first column. Yet the output still has `NEWKEY` in its original place. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply place the `retain` statement before the `set` :

```
data combined ;
  retain newkey ;
  set combined ;
run ;
```

You can simplify this to just one step :

```
data combined ;
  retain newkey ;
  merge set1 (in=in1) 
        set2 (in=in2) ;
  by key ;
  if in1 and in2 ;
run ;
```